# Whats does CS_IME style means in the context of RegisterClass() in winApi

Tags: c++, winapi

Does anybody know what `CS_IME` style means in the context of the `RegisterClass()` function in WinApi?

MSDN lists it as undocumented. The following class-style is undocumented:

```
#define CS_IME 0x00010000
```

Comment: It is intentionally undocumented, info that's only available to the kind of companies that have a partnership agreement with Microsoft.  The kind that would be interested in creating their own Input Method Editor and tend to do business in Eastern Asia.  A window created from that class can always be found with the "IME" class name, regardless of its actual class name.

Comment: tnx, if u post as answer i'll mark it.